# How to indent text exactly one character width

Tags: css, fonts, text-indent

The precondition is that I use **monospace** as my **font-family**, but it doesn't seem to work properly, I've tried some solution but neight of them work, my HTML structure is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: monospace;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    word-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 32px; /* large enough to see the effect */
  }
  div:last-of-type {
    padding-left: 1em; /* what's the value? */
  }
</style>
<div>123456</div>
<div>abcdef</div>
```

1. use **em**

   **em** should be equals to the **computed font-size** value, but **padding-left: 1em;** doesn't work:

   [image: em]
2. use **px**

   **padding-left: 32px;** makes the same output as **padding-left: 1em;**.
3. use **ex**

   **ex** should be the **computed height of the letter 'x'**, and it doesn't work either:

   [image: ex]
4. use **ch**

   OK, webkit *doesn't* support **ch** as a css unit.

So how can I write the css to exactly indent the second div **one character width**, that is, the first '0' should be left-aligned to the letter 'b', without any deviation.

Comment: em and ex measure the font _height_, not the width. You can try `div:last-of-type:before {content:"\00A0"}` but that won't work on all browsers either.

Comment: FYI, you can indent a block of text using `text-indent:-1ex;padding-left:1ex;` (any size of text, multiline text)

Comment: @RobW Yes you can, but 1ex is not the width of a character, which is the OP's problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possible way, although a bit hacky, would be to insert a space before the row using the `:before` pseudo selector with `content`:

```
div:last-of-type:before {
    content: " ";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

I have no idea as to which browsers support this, but I'd assume all modern browsers would.

http://jsfiddle.net/cavqM/

Comment: Yes my target browser (Firefox 6+, Chrome 15+, IE9+) all supports, it seems a good idea, thanks

Comment: However it envolves another problem, the ::before pseudo element doesn't make a **inherit** style, that is, if I use **padding-left**, a `<div><div><div></div></div></div>` structure would indent step by step, but using ::before pseudo element doesn't work this way in my "a bit complex" DOM structure...

Answer (score 7):

Based on the Tatu's approach you can use a unicode representation of a none breakable space like `&nbsp;`

```
div:last-of-type:before {
   content: "\00a0"; /* this is &nbsp; */
}
```

HTH,

--hennson